# Cannot find -lHalide when compiling a toy program

Tags: c++11, installation, halide

I've been trying to install and use Halide.

I installed Halide by doing the following:

I cloned the Halide repo then executed the following commands from the root of the repository.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
sudo make install
```

After the installation finished, I created a file(test.cpp) in an unrelated directory with the following contents:

```cpp
#include "Halide.h"  // <~~ changing this to <Halide.h> also results in the same error

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

I try to compile it with:
`gcc -g -Wall -pedantic -o test test.cpp -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -std=c++11` which gives me the following eror message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHalide
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried the following with (surprisingly; given that there's no ../include or ../bin directory) the same result:

```
g++ test.cpp -g -I ../include -L ../bin -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -o test -std=c++11
```

Edit:

I can see that I do have a file called `Halide.h` under `/usr/local/include/` how do I make gcc see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile correctly it needs a bunch of files to be "included"(not sure if this is the right terminology) as well as the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH be set to the parent directory of the file `libHalide.so`

The following is a Makefile that works:

```
HALIDE_ROOT?=/usr/local/
HALIDE_BUILD?=${HALIDE_ROOT}

HALIDE_TOOLS_DIR=${HALIDE_ROOT}/tools/
HALIDE_LIB_CMAKE:=${HALIDE_BUILD}/lib
HALIDE_LIB_MAKE:=${HALIDE_BUILD}/bin

HALIDE_LIB:=libHalide.so

HALIDE_LIB_DIR=${HALIDE_LIB_MAKE}

HALIDE_INCLUDES:=-I${HALIDE_BUILD}/include -I${HALIDE_ROOT}/tools -L${HALIDE_LIB_DIR}

LIBS:=-ldl -lpthread -lz

.PHONY:         clean

all:        build/test

CC = g++ -Wall -pedantic -O2 -g -std=c++11
HALIDE_REQ = -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -std=c++11


build/test:     test.cpp
    $(CC) ${HALIDE_INCLUDES} intro.cpp -o build/test ${LIBS} -lHalide


clean:
    rm ./build/*
```